# Linking Facebook's Like button to my Fan page

Tags: facebook

Facebook recently launched the new [embeddable Like button](http://www.troublefixers.com/embed-facebook-like-or-recommend-widget-button-in-your-website/). I previously setup a Facebook Fan Page for my site. Can I link the Like button to my fan page?

The fan page is important to me because I'm syndicating content to it. However, I like the Like application because it's dynamic and shows how many people like something. Is there a way to combine them?

**Edit** - to clarify, I don't want to just add the Like button, I'd like it to be linked to the existing fan page. E.g., users that already liked my existing Fan page should already (automatically) appear as liking the new Like widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use a "like box" instead of a "like button":
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

to sort out your 'Facebook Page ID' just log on to your fan page and check the url. 
the number at the end of the url is your page id.

Answer (score 2):

I've stunmbled upon this question using Google and the other answers are not correct anymore. See this blogpost from Facebook Developers: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/407/

Which show this is actually simply possible from 9 september 2010 by using the URL of the facebook page as the URL to be liked by the LIKE button.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what it is you actually want to do? As the link you provided seems to answer your own question.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. The link does not answer my question - it doesn't say anything about linking a Like and an existing Fan page.

Answer (score 0):

The Like button can be hacked to act like a like box.  Generate both using the facebook tools to do so then copy the href code of the like box into the url code of the like button.